# How to perform boolean AND on matrix using vector in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to perform a boolean AND operation on a matrix using a vector. For example, given:

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame([[True, False], [True, False], [True, False]], columns=["A", "B"])
vector = pd.Series([False, False, False])
```

The result would be column-wise boolean AND, like:

```
result = pd.DataFrame([[False, False], [False, False], [False, False]], columns=["A", "B"])
```

I was able to achieve that using a loop, but I'm wondering - is there a more elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
matrix.apply(lambda x: x & vector)
```

**Output**

```
       A      B
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
```

It is implied here that the `axis` parameter of the `apply` function is `0` for columnwise apply.

Answer (score 1):

I would drop down to `numpy` that way you can avoid the loop and broadcast over the correct axis. Then reconstruct the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(matrix.to_numpy() & vector.to_numpy()[:, None],
             columns=matrix.columns,
             index=matrix.index)

       A      B
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
```

---

Alternatively you can `transpose` the DataFrame allowing a simple `&` comparison and then `transpose` the result back. This might get slow for large DataFrames

```
(matrix.T & vector).T
```

Comment: Thank you. I accepted another answer but this one contains useful additional information.

Comment: @PWolf yup, no worries, I think the other solution is a lot more straightforward :D . As always you can still upvote any answers you find useful